# Django query: Joining two models with two fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class AcademicRecord(models.Model):
    record_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    subjects = models.ManyToManyField(Subject,through='AcademicRecordSubject')
    ...


class AcademicRecordSubject(models.Model):
    academic_record = models.ForeignKey('AcademicRecord')
    subject = models.ForeignKey('Subject')
    language_group = IntegerCharField(max_length=2)
    ...


class SubjectTime(models.Model):
    time_id = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject)
    language_group = IntegerCharField(max_length=2)
    ...


class Subject(models.Model):
    subject_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True,primary_key=True)
    ...
```

The academic records have list of subjects each with a language code and the subject times have a subject and language code.

With a given `AcademicRecord`, how can I get the subject times that matches with the `AcademicRecordSubjects` that the `AcademicRecord` has?

This is my approach, but it makes more queries than needed:

```
# record is the given AcademicRecord
times = []
for record_subject in record.academicrecordsubject_set.all():
    matched_times = SubjectTime.objects.filter(subject=record_subject.subject)
    current_times = matched_times.filter(language_group=record_subject.language_group)
    times.append(current_times)
```

I want to make the query using django ORM not with raw SQL

`SubjectTime` language group has to match with `Subject`'s language group aswell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it, in part thanks to @Robert Jørgensgaard Eng

My problem was how to do the inner join using more than 1 field, in which the `F` object came on handly.
The correct query is:

```
SubjectTime.objects.filter(subject__academicrecordsubject__academic_record=record,
                           subject__academicrecordsubject__language_group=F('language_group'))
```

Comment: The `F` expression is indeed the key to the solution here

Answer (score 5):

Given an `AcademicRecord` instance `academic_record`, it is either

```
SubjectTime.objects.filter(subject__academicrecordsubject_set__academic_record=academic_record)
```

or

```
SubjectTime.objects.filter(subject__academicrecordsubject__academic_record=academic_record)
```

The results reflect all the rows of the join that these ORM queries become in SQL.  To avoid duplicates, just use `distinct()`.

Now this would be much easier, if I had a django shell to test in :)

Comment: The SubjectTime language has to also match with the academicrecordsubject's language

Comment: Now I am sorry that I missed that :). The models.F is definitely the way to go as you point out.

Did you just award yourself the 50 points :D

Comment: No I didn't, I was waiting if any other reply came up. I'll give you the bounty.